# swiftui list view layout issue

Tags: list, listview, swiftui

I have made a "RowView" and would like to display each of the row in a List using swiftUI.

My I would like each of the row to be like this:
[image]

and therefore I have written the code. Based on the GeometryReader, I would like to have the row occupy 1/4 of the screen height and then full width, with padding and round corner.

The code I have written is as follows:

```
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        GeometryReader {g in
            ZStack {

                Image("Dummy")                      
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: g.size.width, height: g.size.height/4)
                    .frame(width: g.size.width)
                    .clipped(antialiased: true)
                    .cornerRadius(25)

                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: "photo.on.rectangle.angled")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width:g.size.height/18, height: g.size.height/18)
                        Text("A Long Titlte here................")
                            .font(.title2)
                            .bold()
                            .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
                        Spacer()
                    }.background(Color.red)
                }.frame(width: g.size.width, height: g.size.height/6)
                .frame(width: g.size.width, height: g.size.height/12)
                .background(Color.white)
                .opacity(0.7)
                .offset(y:g.size.height/18)
                
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

After I have made this RowView, I create the ListView.

The code as follows:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        GeometryReader{ g in
        List {
            ForEach(modelData.rows) { row in
                RowView(property: row)
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("ListView")
        }
    }
}
```

However, the height of the row is not as expected, but shrink.

[image]

I do not want to 'hardcode' the height of the row. Any way to make the ListView that shows each of the RowView according to what I have set in the RowView?

Comment: What happens if you give the row in the list view a height of g.size.height/4?

Answer (score 0):

You have two `GeometryReader`s (one wrapping the other) that has the potential to yield some funny effects, especially since the inner one is inside a `List`, which is also a `ScrollView`.

What about only using the outside one (the one around the list) and passing the height as a parameter (or frame modifier) to the inner view?

Something like:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        GeometryReader{ g in
        List {
            ForEach(modelData.rows) { row in
                RowView(property: row)
                 .frame(height: g.size.height / 4)
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("ListView")
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your row, you have two `frame` modifiers in a row right now on your `VStack`.  Get rid of whatever is extraneous there.

Answer (score 0):

I too have found a solution.

The `GeometryReader` works with the `height` and `width` of the parent container that is available.

So you would have to give the parent container a fixed height. You can work with screen sizes to achieve your desired result.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        GeometryReader{ g in
            List {
                ForEach(modelData.rows) { row in
                    RowView(property: row)
                        .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height/4) // <--
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("ListView")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I've avoid using UIScreen.main.bounds.size. It may cause problem especially the UIView is a sheetView, or when the screen get rotated. I realise that it will always caused incorrect layout.